# First time web scraping from a weathercast website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am learning web scraping as my first mini-project. Currently working with python. I want to extract a weather data and use python to show the weather where I am living, I have found the data I needed by inspecting the tags but it keeps giving me all the numbers on the weather forecast table instead of the specific one I need I have tried for to write its specific index number but it still did not work. This is the code I have written so far;

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url= "http://kktcmeteor.org/tahminler/merkezler?m=ISKELE"
r= requests.get(url)

cast = bs(r.content, "lxml")

wthr = cast.findAll("div",{"class": "col-md-9"})
print (wthr)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The data I want is the Temperature data.

Also; Can somebody explain to me the differences between using lxml or html.parser. I have seen both methods being used widely and was curious how would you decide to use one over the other.

Comment: Please clarify what you exactly expect to get, there are a few temperature information on the site.

Comment: If you go to the URL I have posted it's under the name "Sicaklik" which can be translated to "temperature".

Answer (score 1):

Legality of scraping should be considered before the action. You can find something about it here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_web_scraping/legality_of_python_web_scraping.htm
This site doesn't have robots.txt file so it is permitted to crawl.
Here is a very simplified way to get the table data published at the url that you use in the question. This uses html.parser to extract data

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_soup(my_url):
    HTML = requests.get(my_url) 
    my_soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML.text, 'html.parser') 
    if 'None' not in str(type(my_soup)):
        return my_soup
    else:
        return None

url = "http://kktcmeteor.org/tahminler/merkezler?m=ISKELE"

#   get the whole html document
soup = get_soup(url)

#   get something from that soup
#   here a table header and data are extracted from the soup
table_header = soup.find("table").findAll("th")
table_data = soup.find("table").findAll("td")

#   header's and data's type is list
#   combine lists
for x in range(len(table_header)):
    print(table_header[x].text + ' --> ' + table_data[x].text)

""" R e s u l t :
Tarih / Saat -->

Hava --> COK BULUTLU
Sıcaklık --> 27.5°C
İşba Sıcaklığı --> 17.9°C
Basınç --> 1003.5 hPa
Görüş --> 10 km
Rüzgar --> Batıdan (270) 5 kt.
12.06.2022 13:00 --> Genel Tablo Genel Harita
"""
```

This is just one way to do it and it gets just a part shown in a transparent table on the site. Once more, take care of the instructions stated in the robots.txt file of the site. Regards...

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

Comment: So the method names for findAll() have been renamed to find_all()? What exactly is the difference between the two?

Comment: If you swap html.parser with lxml or html5lib you could get a different tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think element is `<div class="temp">24.2 °c</div>.`

If your primary focus is just temperature data, you can check out weather APIs. There are several public APIs you could find [here](https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the webservice has an api you can use? Many weather-apps have api's you can use for free if you stay under a certain limit of requests. If there is, you could easily request only the data you need, so there is no need of formatting it.

Comment: Hello, I have checked and there is no API for the website I want to request the weather data from. It is a very old and badly constructed website (apparently). My friend who has been coding for some years now told me it would be a great problem-solving exercise for me to pull the weather data from that website since it has a badly constructed code.